# How to mount encoder without rear shaft?

Tags: wheeled-robot, quadrature-encoder

I am interested in this robot chasis:

[4 wheel robot chasis](https://www.robotshop.com/en/iron-man-3-4wd-all-terrain-chassis-arduino.html)

There is no information on how to install encoders although the manual says it has space for encoders.

The page says that the motors do not have rear shaft, so, I was wondering if I can use encoders on this chassis, and if so, how can they be mounted? I do not want to mount them on the wheels.

Comment: Link does not work for me. Also, have you aksed their support?

Comment: I updated the link, yes I already asked on their forum.

Comment: the picture shows otherwise .... i think that they may be referring to a rear output from the gearbox ... some gearboxes have two output shafts